# vuetify : how to import only needed components in vuetify when using laravel + vite + inertiajs + vue?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js, vite, inertiajs

I manually imported vuetify by using `npm i vuetify@^3.3.7` and pasted this code in my `app.js` folder:

```
import "vuetify/styles"; import { createVuetify } from "vuetify";
import * as components from "vuetify/components";
import * as directives from "vuetify/directives";

const vuetify = createVuetify({
    components,
    directives,
});
```

Here's the screenshot of my `app.js`

[image: app.js]

I also installed a plugin called `vite-plugin-vuetify` and added these lines of code in my `vite.config.js` file.

```
import vuetify from "vite-plugin-vuetify";
...
vuetify({ autoImport: true }),
```

Here's the screenshot of my `vite.config.js` file

[image: vite.config.js]

My problem is... whenever I load my project in the web browser, all the unnecessary vuetify components that weren't included in my project are automatically loaded which then causes a slow load in my project.

Here's the screenshot of my project's network tab for your reference

[image: Browser network tab]

So my question is: how can I manually import specific components that I am only going to use in my Vue files?

Comment: Do not post images of code or config, post the text literally, because when the images go down, the question is useless for everybody else...

Answer (score 1):

[Automatic treeshaking with Vuetify](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#automatic-treeshaking)  can be accomplished by adding `vite-plugin-vuetify` to `vite.config.js` (which you've already done), and then removing the following imports from `main.js` (in your case `app.js`):

```js
import * as components from 'vuetify/components'
import * as directives from 'vuetify/directives'
```

Comment: Hello, sir @yoduh

Hello, sir. Do I need to remove this block of codes as well?

`const vuetify = createVuetify({ components, directives, });`

Comment: `createVuetify()` takes an object of options.  `components` and `directives` are two possible options which you were importing and adding to the options object.  Since they are now gone, that line of code reduces to `const vuetify = createVuetify()` (no options needed)

Comment: I have the same configuration as provided in the answer and [here](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/features/treeshaking/#automatic-treeshaking), but it still loads all components. Anything I might be missing?